# Coloring nodes according to an attribute in osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I was trying to color the nodes of my network according to a specific attribute, however the function `ox.plot.get_node_colors_by_attr()` isn't work.

The error is: `ValueError: There are no attribute values.`

**Here is the code:**

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive', simplify=True)

G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_nx, nodes=True, edges=True)

r_total = np.random.random(len(G_nx))
nodes['r'] = nodes.index.map(lambda x: r_total[x])
nodes.head()
nc = ox.plot.get_node_colors_by_attr(G_nx, attr='r')
```

Comment: You have added the attribute `'r'` to your data frame `nodes` and not to your graph `G_nx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the lines

```
nodes['r'] = nodes.index.map(lambda x: r_total[x])
nodes.head()
```

with

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G_nx, {x:r_total[x] for x in nodes.index}, name='r')
```

your code should work (documentation of [`set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html)) - even if I don't understand why you assign random values in such a complicated way, but I guess this is only to have a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, it was just for the example, r_total is actually a list with specific data. Thank you for the answer